# Load JSON in SwiftUI with arbitrary keys

Tags: json, swiftui

I have a pretty simple JSON file I would like to load into a SwiftUI project. The JSON file looks like this:

```json
{
  "all": ["foo", "bar", "baz", ...],
  "4": ["asd", "qwe", ...],
  "25": ["something", "another", ...],
  ...
  "2": ["xxx", "yyy", ...]
}
```

Pretty simple, a dictionary where each value is a list of strings. The keys are `"all"` and then an arbitrary number of integers such as `"1"`, `"123"` and so on. They must not be in order, they can be any number, and there may be any number of them. So I don't know before hand how many keys there are.

I have managed to get this JSON into a variable of type `String`. But now I am stuck with how to parse this so I can for example fetch the list at key `"all"`, or check if the key `"123"` exists and if so get that list.

How do I do that in SwiftUI?

Oh, and by the way, the string are Unicode and contain special characters like åäö.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this approach:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var dataList: [String:[String]] = [:]
    
    var body: some View {
        List(Array(dataList.keys), id: \.self) { key in
            Section(header: Text(key).foregroundColor(.red).font(.headline)) {
                if let values = dataList[key] {
                    ForEach(values, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text("\(item)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            .onAppear {
                let json = """
{
  "all": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
  "4": ["asd", "qwe"],
  "25": ["something", "another"],
  "2": ["xxx", "yyy", "åäö"],
  "åäö": ["qwerty", "uiop", "dfghjkh"]
}
"""
                if let data = json.data(using: .utf8) {
                    do {
                        self.dataList = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: [String]].self, from: data)
                    } catch {
                        print("decode error: \(error)")
                    }
                }
                
            }
    }
    
}
```